# Prevent duplicate polymorphic records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, polymorphism, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails 5 app with a Relations table. The table columns looks like:

fromable (polymorphic)
toable (polymorphic)

I want to prevent users from saving relations that are duplicates (that is, that have the same fromable and toable). I've tried to do the following:

```
class Relation < ApplicationRecord

   ...

   belongs_to :fromable, polymorphic: true
   belongs_to :toable, polymorphic: true

   validate :is_not_duplicate_relation

   private

   def is_not_duplicate_relation
      errors.add(:base, "DUPLICATE") if Relation.where(toable: self.toable).where(fromable: self.fromable)
   end
end
```

But this seems to trigger invalid on everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [uniqueness validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness) instead of writing your own to handle this::

```
validates_uniqueness_of :fromable_id, scope: [:toable_id, :toable_type, :fromable_type], allow_nil: true
```

It will automatically check the combination of fromable and toable objects for uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `.exists?` if you are only checking for truthy or falsey. 
eg:

`if Relation.exists?(toable: self.toable, fromable: self.fromable)
  errors.add(:base, "DUPLICATE")
end`

Answer (score 0):

`Relation.where(toable: self.toable).where(fromable: self.fromable)` returns *a relation object*, which is always `truthy`.

You should explicitly check for it’s emptiness:

```
unless Relation.where(toable: self.toable).where(fromable: self.fromable).empty?
```

Comment: This will break when updating the record. `Relation...empty?` will return `false` even if current record is the only one with such attributes.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh indeed; one might check for `count == persisted? ? 1 : 0`.